# How do I make the image change automatically after a certain time?

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, toggle

With each click on one of the menus, it brings a new image, I wanted it to return after a while to the default image.

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {

        R.id.nav_sair -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logue novamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            true
        }

        R.id.nav_sobre -> {
            binding.imvTroca.setImageResource(R.drawable.perfectaprint_quemsomos_full_editado)
            true
        }

        R.id.nav_impressoras -> {
            binding.imvTroca.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem_impressoras_edit)
            true
        }

        R.id.nav_produtos_materiais -> {
            binding.imvTroca.setImageResource(R.drawable.produtos_materiais)
            true
        }

        R.id.nav_fornecedores -> {
            binding.imvTroca.setImageResource(R.drawable.fornecedores)
            true
        }

        else -> {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

        }

    }

}
```

}

With each click on one of the menus, it brings a new image, I wanted it to return after a while to the default image.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a coroutine that you can replace if it gets interuppted.

```
private val imvTrocaImageChangeJob: Job? = null

private fun setTemporaryImvTrocaImage(imageResId: Int) {
    imvTrocaImageChangeJob?.cancel() // interrupt any existing image change job
    imvTrocaImageChangeJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
       binding.imvTroca.setImageResource(imageResId)
        delay(2000L) // 2000 milliseconds
       binding.imvTroca.setImageResource(R.drawable.the_original_image)
    }
}
```

```
    // ...

    R.id.nav_produtos_materiais -> {
        setTemporaryImvTrocaImage(R.drawable.produtos_materiais)
        true
    }

    // etc. ...
```

Comment: It is not accepting the command "setImageResource"
I've already imported the dependency.

Comment: Sorry, bad copy-pasting in my code. See fixed code above.